# Why do I have a horizontal scrollbar with css & html

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I've set up a simple flask based website with some html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{ url_for('static', filename='common.css') }}>
</head>


<div id="main_div">

<form action="/login" method="post">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Username">
      <br><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="button">
</form>

</div>

</html>
```

This is the accompanying css file:

```
#button {
  border: .0;
  background: lightgrey;
  font-size: large;
  color: grey;

}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  width: auto;
}

head {
    background: green;
}

#main_div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background: transparent;
}


form {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  }

p{
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
}
```

I'm trying to make the mobile friendly and am trying to avoid pixel based measurements. The problem is that in desktop mode I keep getting this horizontal scrollbar. I don't want to do just hide the scrollbar, I want to stay in the realm of the view port only. Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: Unrelated to the scrollbar issue, but it's not a good habit to specify styling for `<html>` or `<head>` tags, as they are not visible elements

Comment: @senox13 thank you! I'll remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing position to absolute in form element should help:

```
form {
 text-align: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50vh;
 left: 50vw;
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!